# JavaScript: Add up numbers in nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I'm trying to get the average price, multiplie price and add up qty of nested array of objects but i dont know how to get te right result can somebody help. Thanks in advance

Array type:

```
[
CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
CreatAsset_kcop95ya: (2) [{…}, {…}]
CreatAsset_kcoprqc4: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
CreatAsset_kcqjmhyh: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
]
```

Object data:

```js
[
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 207.88 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1594829893159" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "50" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  },
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 9.88 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1593868712336" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "30.00" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  },
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 98.8 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1594829859268" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "100" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  }
];
```

Result i want:

(totalPrice = latestPrice * purchaseQty ),
(avgPrice = (latestPrice index[0] + latestPrice index[1] + latestPrice index[2] / 3)

```js
{
  avgPrice: {
    stringValue: 105.52
  }
  totalPurchaseQty: {
    stringValue: "180"
  }
  totalPrice1: {
    stringValue: "10394.00"
  }
  totalPrice2: {
    stringValue: "296.40"
  }
  totalPrice3: {
    stringValue: "9880.00"
  }
  waterMark: {
    stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7"
  }
}
```

My Code:

```js
(result is the Array type of above)

let latestPrice = [];
for (let i in result) {
  if (result.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    result[i].map((res) => {
      latestPrice.push({
        latestPrice: res.latestPrice.stringValue,
        waterMark: res.waterMark.stringValue,
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code as valid JSON or JavaScript.

Comment: You say you want `avgPrice` to be the sum of every `latestPrice` divied by the sum of every `purchaseQty`, but in your example you actually computed it as the sum of every `latestPrice` divided by the length of the array.

Comment: @GirkovArpa yes you are right sorry i'm going to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Object.entries(data).forEach(([watermark, array]) => {
  data[watermark] = array.reduce((result, object, i) => {
    const { latestPrice, purchaseQty } = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object)
      .map(([key, { stringValue }]) => ([key, +stringValue])));
    result['totalPrice' + (i + 1)] = latestPrice * purchaseQty;
    result.avgPrice += latestPrice;
    result.totalPurchaseQty += purchaseQty;
    i == array.length - 1 && (result.avgPrice /= array.length);
    return result;
  }, { avgPrice: 0, totalPurchaseQty: 0, watermark });
});
```

Live example:

```js
const data = {
  CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7: [
    {
      latestPrice: { stringValue: 207.88 },
      purchaseDate: { stringValue: '1594829893159' },
      purchaseQty: { stringValue: '50' },
      waterMark: { stringValue: 'CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7' }
    }, {
      latestPrice: { stringValue: 9.88 },
      purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1593868712336" },
      purchaseQty: { stringValue: "30.00" },
      waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
    }, {
      latestPrice: { stringValue: 98.80 },
      purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1594829859268" },
      purchaseQty: { stringValue: "100" },
      waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
    }
  ]
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([watermark, array]) => {
  data[watermark] = array.reduce((result, object, i) => {
    const { latestPrice, purchaseQty } = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object)
      .map(([key, { stringValue }]) => ([key, +stringValue])));
    result['totalPrice' + (i + 1)] = latestPrice * purchaseQty;
    result.avgPrice += latestPrice;
    result.totalPurchaseQty += purchaseQty;
    i == array.length - 1 && (result.avgPrice /= array.length);
    return result;
  }, { avgPrice: 0, totalPurchaseQty: 0, watermark });
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are after something like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 207.88 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1594829893159" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "50" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  },
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 9.88 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1593868712336" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "30.00" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  },
  {
    latestPrice: { stringValue: 98.8 },
    purchaseDate: { stringValue: "1594829859268" },
    purchaseQty: { stringValue: "100" },
    waterMark: { stringValue: "CreatAsset_kcnuvkr7" }
  }
];

const average = arr => arr.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0) / arr.length;
console.log("Average Price", average(data.map(d => d.latestPrice.stringValue)));

const total = data.map(d =>
  (d.latestPrice.stringValue * d.purchaseQty.stringValue).toFixed(2)
);
console.log("Total prices:", total);

const totalPurchaseQty = data
  .map(d => d.purchaseQty.stringValue)
  .reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
console.log("Total Purchse quantity:", totalPurchaseQty);
```

It's just fun, enjoyable functional programming. You can use `.map()` to transform your objects in the values you want to work with and apply your formulas from there. :)